# Does extracting functions affect performance?

Tags: c++

I'm considering dissecting long functions to several smaller ones and I'm concerned about performance. Say we have a long function with many lines of code:

```
void f(){
....
}
```

Now if we extract pieces of work to separate functions:

```
void f(){
  f1();
  f2();
  f3();
}
```

Does it usually affect performance? I'm in search of a **general** **strategy** to balance performance and good software design. Is it always a good practice to have small functions? assume a class with a private member variable `int something`. Is it free to return it by calling `get_something()` instead of making `something` public?

Assume functions as non-virtual and optimization level on `/O3`. The importance of the question is that if the first version is faster we will face a trade-off between maintainability and performance.

Comment: Refactor and profile.  If the performance is acceptable then use the smaller more maintainable functions.

Comment: The first rule is - do not micro-optimize. The second rule is - do not micro-optimize. I am certain that there are other areas for improvements in your app.

Comment: If any of `f1` or `f3`, is costly, then the function call would be negligible. Else, chance are that the function be inlined if present in same translation unit. So write more readable code by splitting your function.

Comment: Good software design makes the software easier to optimize, making it perform better. I see no balance here, performance and good design go hand in hand. I recommend you invest 2 hours to [learn about compiler optimizations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnGCDLhaxKU).

Comment: if the compiler does not inline the functions, there will be cache line misses for each function, if the functions contain parameters then a stack frame needs to be constructed and the parameters need to be passed in and out.  But if the functions are non-trivial, and only small parameters are passed (or large parameters are passed by reference, the function call overhead should be negligible.  The time invested learning how to profile would be well spent.  Compiler optimizations, and cache effects can be surprising.

Comment: **Time it**. If you are calling f() hundreds of billions of times on the critical path then maybe it will cost you something. Weather that amount is an issue compared to time saved in readability is something you will have to decide.

Comment: @SergeyA: I know what you mean by `do not micro-optimize` (as in don't think about it write the most clear code first). But as written an inexperienced developer may read that as (don't split it into separate functions that's trying to optimize).

Comment: @LokiAstari, didn't really occured to me it could be read this way! I will try to be more clear next time.

Comment: It seems every one agrees on having more manageable code. Thank you guys for the great discussion. @nwp Thanks. That's a very good video I've been missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your functions are simple the compiler will usually inline them for you, thus there will be no overhead.

Even if the compiler does not inline your functions, they would have to be part of a *very* hot path if the overhead of a function call was to matter.

Strive to write readable code first and worry about performance second.
And only optimize for performance after you have profiled your application (with optimizations enabled) and demonstrated that the code in question is an actual performance bottleneck.

Comment: You really, really can't guess where the performance bottlenecks in your code lie.  I have been optimizing code for 35 years, and managed to guess right about twice - you have to measure *then* you can optimize that hotspot.  More to the point, if you have simple, straight-forward functions (that inevitably call lots of other functions), you can afford to make one of them 10 times more complicated in order to improve the algorithm (for example by caching previous results, or changing an algorithm from O(n²) to O(n.lg(n))

Comment: @Martin Bonner Isn't that what I said when I said to profile the code?

Comment: It is.  I am just trying to ram it home for the OP.

Comment: Does this still apply for embedded software where processing power and memory are very constrained ?